# Math operations with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, datepicker

I'm working on a form which will calculate something.

This is my form:

```
<form>
    from: 
    <input id="datepicker" readonly='true'/><br>
    to: 
    <input id="datepicker1" readonly='true'/><br>
    number:
    <input id="number" maxlength="15"/> <br />
</form>

<button>Calculate</button>
```

I'm trying to write a code that would do this:

- Subtract Date 2 and Date 1 to get number of days between to inputs
- Get the number of days in selected month
- When you enter number in 3rd field I want to divide that number with number of days in that month and multiply it with subtraction result from 1st bullet (date 2 - date 1)

2nd datepicker isn't necessary if I could somehow make it automatically recognize how many days are in the month selected in 1st field.

I'm still new in JS and I did some testing and I can't get the result I want, I made the operation that subtracts date 2 from date 1 and operation that can do simple math operations with 2 entered values (+, -, *, /) but can't manage to make this work.

Thank a lot in advance.

Comment: There are already many, many questions about [how to perform date arithmetic in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=javascript%20date%20arithmetic) -- please start with those.

Comment: Your question should show the code you used to test it and explain what you expected to occur and what happened instead.

Comment: This is how i substracted 2 date values, but I don't know how to add other functions to this. Been doing my research but no luck
http://jsfiddle.net/Md3q5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a demo in this [JSFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/NNU44/1/)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();

$("button").click(function(){
     var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate'),
        date1   = $("#datepicker1").datepicker('getDate');

    var diffDays = Math.ceil((date1.getTime() - date.getTime())/1000/3600/24);
    var numDaysMonth = new Date(date1.getYear(), date1.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();
    var division = parseInt($("#number").val())/numDaysMonth*diffDays;
    $('#results').html("Diff days: "+diffDays+"<br>"
                       +"Num days in month: "+numDaysMonth+"<br>"
                       +"3rd field calc: "+division);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything works perfect. Now gonna need some time to figure out what all this means so I can use it afterwards by myself. Thanks :)